# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'displayName' error for random JIRA issues

Tags: jql

I am executing the following query and it keeps throwing an 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute displayName. Yet when checking the JIRA, a proper assignee name is present. I searched for hours and cannot find a solution.

jiraIssues = jira.search_issues('project=JSIX and status IN (Open, Resolved, "QA Verify")', maxResults = 7500)

## Executes insert statements

i = jiraDB.insert()

for issue in jiraIssues:
    i.execute(bugCode=issue.key, summary=issue.fields.summary, priority=issue.fields.priority.name, status=issue.fields.status.name, assignee = issue.fields.assignee.displayName, reporter=issue.fields.reporter.displayName)

```
print 'BugCode:', issue.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you find issue created anonymously ([Allowing users to create issues anonymously](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Allowing+users+to+create+issues+anonymously)) you need to check if issue.fields.reporter is not None, and after that call displayName from object. Assignee and Reporter are different, in [jira api](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-22053) you can see different fields: `assignee` and `reporter`. Check you issue with jira rest api, what will be in field `reporter -> displayName`